# How to implement Array indexer in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I can type

```
Square[,,,] squares = new Square[3, 2, 5, 5];
squares[0, 0, 0, 1] = new Square();
```

In fact, I expect I could keep going adding dimensions to Int.MaxValue though I have no idea how much memory that would require.

How could I implement this variable indexing feature in my own class?  I want to encapsulate a multi dimensional array of unknown dimensions and make it available as a property thus enabling indexing in this manner. Must I always know the size in which case how does Array work?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments, here is what I ended up with - I did think of params but didn't know where to go after that not knowing about GetValue.

```
class ArrayExt<T>
{
  public Array Array { get; set; }

  public T this[params int[] indices] 
  {
      get { return (T)Array.GetValue(indices); }
      set { Array.SetValue(value, indices);}
  }
}

ArrayExt<Square> ext = new ArrayExt<Square>();
ext.Array = new Square[4, 5, 5, 5];
ext[3, 3, 3, 3] = new Square();
```

TBH I don't really need this now. I was just looking for a way to extend Array to initialize its elements having resolved to avoid for loop initialization code outside the class whenever I was using a multi array (mainly in unit tests). Then I hit intellisense and saw the Initialize method...though it restricts me to a default constructor and value types. For reference types an extension method would be required. Still I learnt something and yes, there was a runtime error when I tried an array with more than 32 dimensions.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide just a little more context on how you aim to actually work with a multidimensional array of unknown dimensions. Seeing as .NET doesn't really support that in its type system in any straightforward way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use varargs:

```
class Squares {
    public Square this[params int[] indices] {
        get {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You'd have to handle the fact `indices` can have an arbitrary length yourself, in whicheevr way you feel is appropriate. (E.g. check the size of `indices` against the array rank, type it as `Array` and use [`GetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2cf72s5.aspx).)

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, I added that instead of my humming and hawing.

Answer (score 7):

Arrays types are magic – `int[]` and `int[,]` are two different types, with separate indexers.
These types are not defined in source code; rather, their existence and behavior are described by the spec.

You would need to create a separate type for each dimensionality – a `Matrix1` class with a `this[int]`, a `Matrix2` class with a `this[int, int]`, and so on.

Comment: You can also have a generic `Matrix` have a `this[params int[] indices]` indexer, and translate that into... whatever is appropriate for the OP. (I don't really know what they're going for here.)

Comment: @millimoose: Yes, but that wouldn't be type-safe.

Comment: Indeed not, but that's implied if the OP really needs to use an array of unknown rank. (Which they admittedly might not, hence my comment on the question.)

Answer (score 1):

use the `this[]` operator:

```
public int this[int i, int j]
{
    get {return 1;}
    set { ; }
}
```

Note that you can't have a *variable* number of dimensions in one operator - you have to code each method separately:

```
public int this[int i, int j, int k]
{
    get {return 1;}
    set { ; }
}
public int this[int i, int j]
{
    get {return 1;}
    set { ; }
}
public int this[int i]
{
    get {return 1;}
    set { ; }
}
```

> I expect I could keep going adding dimensions to Int.MaxValue

[You'd be wrong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> An array can have a maximum of 32 dimensions.

Comment: @millimoose: I don't think that's true.

Comment: @millimoose >"How could I implement this variable indexing feature in my own class?"